# Why the tagline "It's nothing personal" for "Terminator 2"?

Tags: terminator-series, posters, terminator-2-judgment-day

One of the taglines for *Terminator 2: Judgment Day* says

> "*It's nothing personal*".
>
> [image]

What is this referring to? I have watched the extended cut, but there seems to be no references to anything being either personal or not.

Why is it a tagline?

Comment: Please post an example scene or of poster/photo of this tagline. Context is helpful.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a subversion of the tagline for Jaws 4 ("*This time, it's personal*")

Comment: @DrMrstheMonarch - https://www.vintagemovieposters.co.uk/shop/terminator-2-judgement-day-movie-poster-2/

Answer (score 9):

"It's Nothing Personal", as seen on the poster just above the movie's name:

[image: T2 Movie Poster]

This was possibly meant to indicate the nature of machines. Schwarzenegger, as you may recall, was the "bad" terminator sent to kill Sarah Connor in the first movie.  In T2, he was sent as the protector of Sarah's son, John.  He was programmed with a mission, and that mission has nothing to do with emotions.  It's cold.  It's uncaring.  But it also has an aire of bad-assery to it.

Also, if I'm not mistaken, Sarah says something along those lines (maybe verbatim) when she goes to kill Miles Dyson in an attempt to create a different timeline where Skynet doesn't exist.

Comment: It also references Jaws 4  "This time it's personal"

Comment: As James K says, the fourth (and final) Jaws movie, _Jaws: The Revenge_, had come out 4 years previously, with the tag line “This time, it's personal.” — a line sufficiently well-known to inspire parodies, albums, etc. (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Time_It%27s_Personal)). I don't have any evidence for this being a direct reference, but I expect many people at the time would have understood it that way.

Answer (score 3):

You have to remember that in the original marketing, they tried to hide the "reveal" that Schwarzenegger's character had been reprogrammed as the "good guy". When the first posters and trailers came out, they were trying to fake-out the audience and make us think the original villain was returning.

The tagline was found on earlier posters, and it works well for Schwarzenegger being either the protagonist or antagonist. In later posters, the tagline was changed to "This time he's back...for good!"

Answer (score 0):

After finishing filming The Abyss, James Cameron was asked what his next film was going to be. Filming The Abyss had been a very difficult process and the last thing he wanted to do at that point was to undertake another big, complex film, so in reply he said "something personal".

His next film after The Abyss was T2, hence the tagline 'Its Nothing Personal'

Comment: Can you provide links to support your answer?